# Editing on mobile UI duplicated my answer instead of editing it

Tags: bug, edits, mobile-web

I posted [an answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/57079/321), then decided I wanted to edit in a quotation. I did so, but it resulted in [a new answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/57081/321) instead of an edit to my original answer. This was in the mobile view on Safari (iOS 8.1.3).

I'm **certain** that it was submitted as an edit, not a new post, since to create a new post I would have had to start editing my original answer, copy its text, scroll down and click "Add Another Answer", paste in my text, and then make the changes, all without realising what I was doing. I did not do something so elaborate and wasn't sleepwalking through the UI, I just used the edit link under my first answer.

Comment: No repro here, maybe it's specific to that site?

Comment: @ShadowWizard It may be, but I can't imagine why. It could also be that some other conditions are necessary that make it a Heisenbug; if it happens again I'll be sure to update. If nothing else, a record here may help further down the line if something similar or related comes up.